# Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition for PS3 includes DLC on disc or as a voucher code?

Tags: ps3, mortal-kombat-x

Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition includes all previously released DLC. But is it loaded on disc or is it a one-time use only voucher code with an expiration date?